# How to get the currently active form in my application?

Tags: delphi

How to get the currently active (focused) form in my application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Screen.ActiveForm` does the trick.

Comment: Beware that if you have an auxiliary temporary modal form that serves information to another form, e.g `InputBox` or `ShowMessage`, that form will be the ActiveForm. Personally I would create a "base" form so all the "wanted" forms would inherit from it and then keep track of the currenctly active form by overriding the WM_ACTIVE message in the base form to feed an global WantedActiveForm variable.

Comment: The approach I mentioned is usefull if you have a timer that checks the active form or something like this. Of course it is not a general rule, in most of the time, Screen.ActiveForm actually does the trick. This WM_ACTIVE thing is needed because `OnActivate` is not fired when you finished using a modal form, were it not for that, one could use `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` instead of overriding `WM_ACTIVE`.

Comment: I think you mean `Screen.ActiveForm`

Answer (score 3):

You can code the following ways :

```
   var CurrentForm: TForm; // Make sure to make it a global variable

  procedure KeyDownEvents(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
    CurrentForm:=Screen.ActiveForm.Name;
    if Key = VK_F9 then CurrentForm.KeyBoard1.Show;
    end;
```

This will fix the issue. Similarly you can handle the form on mouse click and other key press. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to write it for all the key events ?

Comment: If you want you can write it for a particular event or all as per you requirement.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: What issue? What fix? How do you want to assign a string property `Name` to a `TForm` type variable? The rest is also something weird.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked fine for me, no global variable is required and each form **NAME** is unique because Delphi IDE is not accepting duplicate form name.

```
if Screen.ActiveForm.Name = Self.Name then
begin
    // Do your work here
end
```

I used this code to close form when <kbd>ESC</kbd> button is pressed on keyboard and only active/current form should be closed.

Here is the example:

```
if Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then
  begin
    if Msg.wParam = Ord(VK_ESCAPE) then
    begin

      if Screen.ActiveForm.Name = Self.Name then
      begin

        if (MessageDlg('DO YOU WANT TO CLOSE ' + UpperCase(Self.Caption) + ' FORM?',
          mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) in [mrYes]) then
        begin
          Close;
        end;

      end;

    end;

  end;
```

Comment: Why mess with the name? Just test to see `if Screen.ActiveForm = Self`.